# Why is @media changing body properties?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I really can not understand why if I use:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px)
```

The body changes height and margin. Look at this samples:

1) Without @media: http://jsfiddle.net/Clear/xrcxsmpp/

2) With @media: http://jsfiddle.net/Clear/xrcxsmpp/1/

As you can see, I tried also to change the body properties as:

```
body {
    margin: 0 !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Someone who has some idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your semi-colon at the end of your media query is invalidating the body selector!

Just remove that so you only have the closing brace.

**EDIT**

Semi colons in CSS are only valid at the end of an attribute property, other than that its just curly braces all the way

Comment: Thank you very much! Honestly I do not know why I put the semi-colon!